# Как сформулировать запрос к бд?

Tags: mysql

```
tableName:
field1;field2;field3
1;21;1
1;45;2
1;23;3
2;34;4
2;23;5
3;52;6
3;52;7
3;13;8
3;26;9
```

Как получить строки с наименьшими значениями второго столбца по каждому уникальному значению первого столбца?

То есть:

```
1;21;1
2;23;5
3;13;8
```

Comment: Если в исходный пример добавить строчку `3;13;9` какой результат должен быть? или одинаковой пары `field1;field2` не может существовать?

Comment: одинаковая пара field1;field2 есть в примере, но на практике это timestamp, его совпадение маловероятно да и в случае совпадения можно брать любой

Comment: в случае совпадения можно сортировать по field3, так как на одно уникальное field1 не может быть два одинаковых field3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой запрос:

```sql
select tbl1.* 
  from test_tbl tbl1
  inner join (
    select tbl2.field1, min(tbl2.field2) field2 
    from test_tbl tbl2 
    group by tbl2.field1
  ) tbl3
  on tbl1.field1 = tbl3.field1 and tbl1.field2 = tbl3.field2;
```

Тест можно посмотреть [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9fb82/7).